# AngularJS and Firebase, trouble adding data in $firebaseArray

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to AngularJS and Firebase. Currently facing some issues in taking data from a form and putting it in Firebase. I have no console logs, but the data just does'nt go into Firebase hope some kind soul can help me out :(

index.html

```
      <!-- Firebase -->
     <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.5/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "x",
    authDomain: "x",
    databaseURL: "x",
    storageBucket: "x",
    messagingSenderId: "x"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();
</script>
<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

form     (sell.html)

`<h1 id="sell-heading4" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Test</h1>
    <form ng-submit="appsell()">
      <label class="item item-input" id="sell-input4">
        <span class="input-label">Input</span>
        <input placeholder="" type="text" ng-model="name">
      </label>
        <label class="item item-input" id="sell-input4">
        <span class="input-label">Input2</span>
        <input placeholder="" type="text" ng-model="name2">
      </label>
    <button id="sell-button3" class="button button-positive  button-block" >Tap me!</button>
    </form>`

controller.js

```
    .controller('sellCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$firebaseArray', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseArray) {

var ref = firebase.database().ref();

$scope.data = $firebaseArray(ref);

$scope.addsell = function(){
    $scope.data.$add($scope.name1);
    $scope.data.$add($scope.name2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have not linked the controller into your code in index.html. (Using ng-controller directive)